# The app lost badges

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

Some question on some post don't have badges. It seems like it's the 3-4 top posts from the feed on meta. After that, they have the badges.

Galaxy S3 / Android 4.3 / Wifi or 4G

> [image]

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this, let me know if you see it again.

Comment: I see it, @KasraRahjerdi

Comment: @hichris123 can you add more details to the question? What phone/OS version? What data connection?

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi In an edit or via a comment? Anyway, I saw it on a meta question at first. I clicked on it, refreshed it, and then the badges went away. Now I can't see any badges for meta users, but I can for SO users (didn't have the bug on SO).

Comment: As an edit please, exact reproduction steps are the best way to get a bug reported.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi Edited. It seems its not the refresh causing this but the 3-4 top post on meta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the report (and helping me nail down a repro)! The issue has been fixed and will be rolled out in version 0.1.78 coming out sometime around midnight UTC.

Comment: Thanks. Curious. What was causing this ? :P

Comment: One of our [filters](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters) was acting oddly, I think it was made with a version of the API that's newer than what's available right now.

Comment: It is fixed on meta but there is the same problem on other sites. (Sports, seasoned advice) Stopped looking there.